# How to list the tag version of a previously pulled image used within docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tags

Assume you have a `docker-compose.yml` with:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
```

Depending on the current date, it may pull a different minor version, i.e. today it may pull 8.0.27, yet it may have pulled 8.0.11.

I want to use the explicit tag down to the patch version and for that I want to know which one are currently used. (I know that the tag version on my specific machine are known-to-work. The current ones though have an unexpected break in the minor version. I don't want to use the most current tag versions.)

How do I quickly gather the information?

For example, I know that I can find the information in the log file:

```
docker-compose logs mysql
mysql_1                 | 2021-12-16 10:41:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
```

But I am not sure if that was the case for all the containers.

How can I list the tag names of the previously pulled images within a docker-compose stack using either `docker` or `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check image hash by

```
docker images | grep mysql
mysql 8.0 65b636d5542b        29 hours ago        524MB
```

then search at docker hub for tags with this hash/digest (`65b636d5542b` in case above) https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags&page=2&name=8.0